# Why lime tabular method generates type errors with data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, lime

I'm traying to use LIME to explain the results of a gradient boost model.

This is the data I have:

[image]

And the code I'm using:

```
explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(training_data = sample, 
                                                   mode = 'regression',
                                                   training_labels = y_train,
                                                   feature_names = ["x1","x2"])
```

And the error I´m getting:

[image]

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should convert `sample` to a numpy array.

From the [source code](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/blob/master/lime/lime_tabular.py#L119):

> training_data: numpy 2d array